# How do i make a switch that changes my picture depending on which weather id is in a json

Tags: java, android, android-studio, import, openweathermap

I have a weather app that is lacking changing icons/pictures depending on what the weather is, i have searched for hours but not found a solution. Im using `openweathermap` api, and would like to make a switch statement that changes my picture depending on what the weather id is.

Here is my `WeatherActivity.java`.

```
package com.inducesmile.androidweatherapp;
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.text.Html;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.github.pavlospt.CircleView;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.inducesmile.androidweatherapp.adapters.RecyclerViewAdapter;
import com.inducesmile.androidweatherapp.database.DatabaseQuery;
import com.inducesmile.androidweatherapp.entity.WeatherObject;
import com.inducesmile.androidweatherapp.helpers.CustomSharedPreference;
import com.inducesmile.androidweatherapp.helpers.Helper;
import com.inducesmile.androidweatherapp.json.FiveDaysForecast;
import com.inducesmile.androidweatherapp.json.FiveWeathers;
import com.inducesmile.androidweatherapp.json.Forecast;
import com.inducesmile.androidweatherapp.json.LocationMapObject;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

public class WeatherActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener {

    private static final String TAG = WeatherActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;

    private RecyclerViewAdapter recyclerViewAdapter;

    private TextView cityCountry;

    private TextView currentDate;

    private ImageView weatherImage;

    private CircleView circleTitle;

    private TextView windResult;

    private TextView humidityResult;

    private RequestQueue queue;

    private LocationMapObject locationMapObject;

    private LocationManager locationManager;

    private Location location;

    private final int REQUEST_LOCATION = 200;

    private CustomSharedPreference sharedPreference;

    private String isLocationSaved;

    private DatabaseQuery query;

    private String apiUrl;

    private ImageView cat;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_weather);

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if(actionBar != null){
            actionBar.hide();
        }

        queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        query = new DatabaseQuery(WeatherActivity.this);
        sharedPreference = new CustomSharedPreference(WeatherActivity.this);
        isLocationSaved = sharedPreference.getLocationInPreference();

        cityCountry = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.city_country);
        currentDate = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.current_date);
        weatherImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.weather_icon);
        circleTitle = (CircleView)findViewById(R.id.weather_result);
        windResult = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.wind_result);
        humidityResult = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.humidity_result);
        cat = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.cat);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Service.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(WeatherActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_LOCATION);
        } else {
            if(isLocationSaved.equals("")){
                // make API call with longitude and latitude
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 100, 2, this);
                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    apiUrl = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat="+location.getLatitude()+"&lon="+location.getLongitude()+"&APPID="+Helper.API_KEY+"&units=metric";
                    makeJsonObject(apiUrl);
                }
            }else{
                // make API call with city name
                String storedCityName = sharedPreference.getLocationInPreference();
                //String storedCityName = "Enugu";
                System.out.println("Stored city " + storedCityName);
                String[] city = storedCityName.split(",");
                if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(city[0])){
                    System.out.println("Stored city " + city[0]);
                    String url ="http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q="+city[0]+"&APPID="+Helper.API_KEY+"&units=metric";
                    makeJsonObject(url);
                }
            }
        }

        ImageButton addLocation = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.add_location);
        addLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent addLocationIntent = new Intent(WeatherActivity.this, AddLocationActivity.class);
                startActivity(addLocationIntent);
            }
        });

        GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(WeatherActivity.this, 4);



    }


    private void makeJsonObject(final String apiUrl){
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, apiUrl, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Response " + response);
                GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
                Gson gson = builder.create();
                locationMapObject = gson.fromJson(response, LocationMapObject.class);
                if (null == locationMapObject) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Nothing was returned", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Response Good", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    String city = locationMapObject.getName() + ", " + locationMapObject.getSys().getCountry();
                    String todayDate = getTodayDateInStringFormat();
                    Long tempVal = Math.round(Math.floor(Double.parseDouble(locationMapObject.getMain().getTemp())));
                    String weatherTemp = String.valueOf(tempVal) + "°";
                    String weatherDescription = Helper.capitalizeFirstLetter(locationMapObject.getWeather().get(0).getDescription());
                    String windSpeed = locationMapObject.getWind().getSpeed();
                    String humidityValue = locationMapObject.getMain().getHumudity();

                    //save location in database
                    if(apiUrl.contains("lat")){
                        query.insertNewLocation(locationMapObject.getName());
                    }
                    // populate View data
                    cityCountry.setText(Html.fromHtml(city));
                    currentDate.setText(Html.fromHtml(todayDate));
                    circleTitle.setTitleText(Html.fromHtml(weatherTemp).toString());
                    circleTitle.setSubtitleText(Html.fromHtml(weatherDescription).toString());
                    windResult.setText(Html.fromHtml(windSpeed) + " km/h");
                    humidityResult.setText(Html.fromHtml(humidityValue) + " %");

                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error " + error.getMessage());
            }
        });
        queue.add(stringRequest);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_LOCATION) {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    //make api call
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 100, 2, this);
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        apiUrl = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat="+location.getLatitude()+"&lon="+location.getLongitude()+"&APPID="+Helper.API_KEY+"&units=metric";
                        makeJsonObject(apiUrl);
                    }else{
                        apiUrl = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=51.5074&lon=0.1278&APPID="+Helper.API_KEY+"&units=metric";
                        makeJsonObject(apiUrl);
                    }
                }
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(WeatherActivity.this, getString(R.string.permission_notice), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        if (provider.equals(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
            showGPSDisabledAlertToUser();
        }
    }

    private void showGPSDisabledAlertToUser() {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("GPS is disabled in your device. Would you like to enable it?")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Goto Settings Page To Enable GPS", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        Intent callGPSSettingIntent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                        startActivity(callGPSSettingIntent);
                    }
                });
        alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alert = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alert.show();
    }

    private String getTodayDateInStringFormat(){
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("E, d MMMM", Locale.getDefault());
        return df.format(c.getTime());
    }
    private String convertTimeToDay(String time){
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:SSSS", Locale.getDefault());
        String days = "";
        try {
            Date date = format.parse(time);
            System.out.println("Our time " + date);
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTime(date);
            days = calendar.getDisplayName(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SHORT, Locale.getDefault());
            System.out.println("Our time " + days);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return days;
    }
}
```

Here's the WeatherActivity.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/colorBlack"
    tools:context="com.inducesmile.androidweatherapp.WeatherActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/city_country"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_16sdp"
            android:text="@string/city_country"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_24sdp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/current_date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:text="@string/date_today"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_14sdp" />

        <com.github.pavlospt.CircleView
            android:id="@+id/weather_result"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_150sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_150sdp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_8sdp"
            app:cv_backgroundColorValue="@color/colorWhite"
            app:cv_fillColor="@color/colorBlack"
            app:cv_strokeColorValue="@color/colorWhite"
            app:cv_subtitleSize="@dimen/_12sdp"
            app:cv_subtitleText="@string/weather_information"
            app:cv_titleColor="@color/colorWhite"
            app:cv_titleSize="@dimen/_50sdp"
            app:cv_titleSubtitleSpace="40"
            app:cv_titleText="@string/current_temperature" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_12sdp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="3">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_16sdp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/wind"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorSubTitle"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_14sdp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/wind_result"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_4sdp"
                    android:text="@string/wind_speed"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_14sdp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/add_location"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_12sdp"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:elevation="@dimen/_4sdp"
                    android:src="@drawable/cross" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/_16sdp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:text="@string/humidity"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorSubTitle"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_14sdp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/humidity_result"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_4sdp"
                    android:text="@string/humidity_rate"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_14sdp" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

openweather api json returns a icon string according to the given weather. Use the code with URL to loads images.

> http://openweathermap.org/img/w/10n.png

```
{
    "coord": {
        "lon": -0.13,
        "lat": 51.51
    },
    "weather": [
        {
            "id": 500,
            "main": "Rain",
            "description": "light rain",
            "icon": "10n"
        }
    ],
```

further info in this link

> https://openweathermap.org/weather-conditions

further edit for your answer, you do not need a switch statement with this approach -

```
 private static HashMap<String,String> iconMap = new HashMap<String,String>() {
       put("icon code from json", "path to your icon");
}

    //check where the icon is in json callback, not sure about this call ;)
    String icon = locationMapObject.getWeather().get(0).getIcon();

    if(iconMap.contains(icon){
    //update your TextView with icon
    }
```

Comment: how do i make a switch statement that checks for the weather id in that string?

Comment: also just put your icons id in a map and check for the icon id, every time you get the json.

Comment: i have my own set of icons id like to use, is it a possibility?

Comment: and also i dont know how to structure a switch statement for this